# Getting data from different databases ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I want to get data from two contexts and merge it and pass it to the view.

Currently, I did this,

```cs
private zSqlLink dbs = new zSqlLink();
private zSqlData db = new zSqlData();

public ActionResult PendingSelfTasks() 
{
    IEnumerable <SelfCareTasks> pendingTasks = new List <SelfCareTasks> ();

    var list = dbs.SelfCareTasks.ToList().Where(x => x.Is_Service_Accepted == false && x.Status == true);

    var TaskList = (
        from d in list join c in db.Customer on d.Customer_Id equals c.Id 
        join ser in db.Services on d.Service_Id equals ser.Id 
        where d.Is_Service_Accepted == false && d.Status == true 
        select new SelfCareTasks 
        {
            Id = d.Id,
            CustomerName = c.Sur_Name + c.Name,
            ServiceName = ser.Service_NameEng,
            ServicePrice = d.Service_Price,
        }).ToList();

    return View(TaskList);
}
```

What I did was, 1st I created `list` and get the main records from one context and stored them there,
Then I create another list and there I joined the `list` with the other database values to get the data required.
Here for the `list`I'm getting the data and when I merge it with another context returns without data.

Is something I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work and multi-entity Repository. There's no Entity Framework code in the question. The code has serious problems too - that `dbs.SelfCareTasks.ToList()` loads the entire table in memory. That's the worst possible way of bypassing LINQ translation errors

Comment: side notes:
- doing `dbs.SelfCareTasks.ToList()` before your where clause is harmful to the performance. with `ToList()` you are asking the ORM to load EVERY RECORD in your DB in memory, then start to apply filter criteria. you should call `ToList()` once at the end of your where expression, or leave it to be loaded once needed.

Comment: Where are the databases? If they're eg SQL Server databases on the same server, there's no reason to use *two* DbContexts. A DbContext *isn't* a database connection. An entity can be mapped to any table accessible with a three-part name can be used. Worst case, you can create a SQL query that JOINs the two tables. If the databases are on different servers though, you can't JOIN - you wouldn't be able to JOIN in SQL in the first place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the advice ``ToList()`` I'll change that. My databases are on the same SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your model relations are but as you already know you can't make collective query to different databases. You need to make separate queries to each database and map the datа in the code. Of course based on the answer of Panagiotis Kanavos you can have other different opinions

```
private zSqlLink dbs = new zSqlLink();
private zSqlData db = new zSqlData();

public ActionResult PendingSelfTasks() 
{
    //Get the collections from databases separately 
    var list = dbs.SelfCareTasks.Where(x => x.Is_Service_Accepted == false && x.Status == true).ToList();

    var listIds = list.Select(x => x.Id).Tolist();
    var customer = bd.Customer.Where(x => listIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

    //Them map all you need in the code
    foreach(var selfCareTasks in list)
    {
    }
    
    return View(TaskList);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this does what I was required to do.